# Convert object into excel file for MVC web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, object

Example, I have an item object with two properties

```
public class Item {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then...

```
Item item = new Item();
```

How can I pass this 'item' object to convert it into excel and save it to a target folder location.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of libraries available for creating excel files on a server: eg - http://epplus.codeplex.com/   You should not try this using the Interop libraries: it's not a good idea to try and automate Excel in a server environment.

Comment: Yes I already saw the library. What I just want to know is how can I do it manually. Thanks.

Comment: The source code is right there on the site if you want to know the details of how it's done.